# Codeigniter Highcharts Filter not Working

Tags: codeigniter, highcharts

I have some data related with issued items in my codeigniter project those used in a highchart view. And I want to apply filter to filtering branch wise data in the chart.

## Controler

```
<?php
if (!defined("BASEPATH")) {
   exit("No direct script access allowed");
}

class Chart_issue extends CI_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->model("data");
   }

   public function index()
   {
       $this->load->view("charts/chart_issue");
   }

   public function data()
   {
       $data = $this->data->get_issued_data();
       $branch = $this->data->getBranch();

       $category = [];
       $category["name"] = "Item";

       $series1 = [];
       $series1["name"] = "Issued Qty";

       foreach ($data as $row) {
           $category["data"][] = $row->item;
           $series1["data"][] = $row->issued_qty;
       }
       $result = [];
       array_push($result, $category);
       array_push($result, $series1);

       print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
   }
```

}

## Model

```
function getBranch()
    {
        $q = $this->db->get_where('store_branch', array('status' => '1'));
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q->result();
        }
        return FALSE;
    } 
function get_issued_data($id)
{   
    $this->db->select('sur.update_stock_id, sus.branch_id, sus.request_no, sus.billed_date, store_branch.branch_name AS branch,
    si.item_id, si.item_name AS item,   tf.avqty,   sur.r_qty as r_qty, sur.ap_qty as ap_qty, 
    tf1.issued_qty');
    $this->db->from('store_update_request sur');
    $this->db->join('store_update_stock sus', 'sus.update_stock_id=sur.update_stock_id', 'left');       
    $this->db->join('store_branch', 'sus.branch_id=store_branch.branch_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('store_item si', 'sur.item=si.item_id', 'left');        
    
    $this->db->join('(select update_stock_id, item, is_qty AS issued_qty 
        from store_update_issue         
        where store_update_issue.status=1 
        ) AS tf1', 
        'si.item_id=tf1.item AND sur.update_stock_id = tf1.update_stock_id','left' );
                
    $this->db->join('(select item, sum(qty)  AS avqty 
        from store_update_stock_details             
        where store_update_stock_details.status=1 
        group by item) AS tf', 'si.item_id=tf.item', 'left');
    $this->db->where(array('sus.status' => 1, 'sus.branch_id' => $id, 'billed_date >=' => '2023-01-01' ));
  
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
    return false;
}     
}
```

## View

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // 
  < ![CDATA[$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#branch').change(function() {
          var id = $('#branch').val();
          getAjaxData(id);
        });
        var options = {
          chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Item Issued Summary',
            x: -20 //center
          },
          subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
          },
          xAxis: {
            categories: ['']
          },
          yAxis: [{
            title: {
              text: 'Issues'
            },
            plotLines: [{
              value: 0,
              width: 1,
              color: '#808080'
            }]
          }, ],
          tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
              return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b>' + this.x + ': ' + this.y;
            }
          },
          legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
          },
          plotOptions: {
            column: {
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
              }
            }
          },
          series: []
        }
        $.getJSON("data", function(json) {
          options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
          options.series[0] = json[1];
          chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
      });
      // ]]>
</script> <?php
if (!empty($branch)) {
    $common = $branch[0];
}
?> <a href="
<?= site_url('welcome') ?>">
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Back to Home">
</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Item Issued Data </h3>undefined</div>undefined<br></br>undefined<form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on">
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="text" name="range" id="range" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Branch / Section</label>
        <select name="branch" id="branch" class="form-control select2">
          <option value="">Select Branch / Section</option> <?php
                            if (!empty($common)) {
                                foreach ($common as $row) {
                                    ?> <option value="
                <?= $row->branch_id ?>"> <?= $row->branch_name ?> </option> <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>undefined
</form>undefined<script type='text/javascript' src='
```

assets/js/highcharts.js'>

```
  undefined
</script>undefined<script type='text/javascript' src='
```

assets/js/exporting.js'>

```
  undefined
</script>undefined
<link rel="stylesheet" href="
```

assets/css/charts/chart.css">

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="
<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/charts/xcharts.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="
    <?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/charts/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="
        <?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/daterangepicker.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='
            <?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/charts/d3.v2.js'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='
            <?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/charts/sugar.min.js'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='
            <?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/charts/xcharts.min.js'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='
            <?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/charts/script.js'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='
            <?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/daterangepicker.js'>
</script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

## Output

The chart is generated correctly. But the branch dropdown can't populate and didn't apply branch wise filter. What may be missing by me ? Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Hi @MCIT Trends, You have used `highcharts` tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about other functionalities. To apply some filters on a chart, you may need to use `chart.update` https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update, `setData` https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData or some other methods from Highcharts API.